# Definition of a Residue

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I know that the standard definiton of a residue is the $a_{-1}$ coefficient in the Laurent series but if we are trying to work out the residue of a pole of order m does the residue become the $a_{−m}$ coefficient in the Laurent series?

Comment: No, it's always $a_{-1}$. Every function of the form $(z-a)^m$ has an antiderivative except when $m=-1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The idea behind that is: We want to calculate integrals of functions with singularities, and we know that every function of the form $\frac{g(z)}{(z-z_{0})^{n}}$ has a primitive iff $n\neq1$. So using the linearity of the integral, we need to calculate the term that go above $(z-z_{0})$, and by definition is always $a_{-1}$. Hope i've helped you.

Comment: the residue of $f(z)$ at $z=  a$ is the constant such that $f(z)-\frac{C}{z-a}$ is the derivative of a meromorphic function around $a$, ie. $\int_\gamma (f(z)-\frac{C}{z-a})dz = 0$